# drive sdk issue when registering app 'input was invalid'?

Tags: google-drive-api

Ok I am literally tearing my hair out on this one! I am trying to register my app for the google drive sdk. I have imputed everything necessary and i have checked my client id is good literally a hundred times all url's exist ect ect why on earth is it throwing up the 'your input was invalid' error? I have added a screen grab of the page (minus sensitive info)

[drive sdk register app page what's wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0bA4.png)

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the . from the Default File Extensions list. For instance, use "txt" instead of ".txt"

Comment: Wow, I can not believe how obvious that was! Thank you so very much. Why on earth doesn't Google tell us this? Giving us a cryptic error when the problem is so simple, and easy to foresee.